# Move a ball with the accelerometer (simple example)

Tags: android, andengine

Where to find a simple example to move a ball using accelerometer(Andengine) . I make that using onKeyDown events.

int x=20;
iny y=10;

//ballSprite.setPostion(x,y);
Eg: when pressed leftKey

x=x-5;

when Pressed Up key

y=y+5;

The same thing , how to make using accelerometer.. Any samples ?

Comment: Sorry, but have you at least tried to search for it? I used 3 words for my search and came up with that: http://blog.androgames.net/85/android-accelerometer-tutorial/ as you should consider: not everything is "simple" so working with an accelerometer takes some time to understand and some skills in math. Also "simple" is very subjective. Try the tutorial and combine it with andengine... ask if you have a specific problem...

Comment: http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/penner_chapter7_tweening.pdf Book chapter on all aspects of tweening. Explains maths in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following useful;

```
public class AccelerometerScreen extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerometerListener, IOnAreaTouchListener{

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 720;



@Override
public void onLoadResources() {

    this.enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(mTexture);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    }




    @Override
public void onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {  
    accellerometerSpeedX = (int)pAccelerometerData.getX();
            //   accellerometerSpeedY = (int)pAccelerometerData.getY();
    Log.v("Accelerometer X Y Z: ", ""+pAccelerometerData);

    // from this accelerometer data u can set ur sprite. 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Specific to AndEngine... download the [AndEngineExamples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/) and check out the source for the [PhysicsExample](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java). It uses the accelerometer to adjust the gravity of the physics world.

Essentially, all you do is override onAccelerometerChanged to move the ball using the AccelerometerData.